# How to bind click action of NSButton in view based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` that is set to be 'view based', and within each `NSTableCellView` there is an `NSButton` and an `NSTextField`.

The text field is being populated correctly from an array controller. The buttons are appearing correctly but I'm having trouble working out how to hook up the click action.

I thought this would be possible by control-dragging from the `NSButton` in IB to a simple method like this one in my controller (in this case an `NSDocument` subclass):

```
- (IBAction)testAction:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Test action");
}
```

It connects fine but never gets fired. Any ideas why this is or how to fix it?

Comment: There is a very good  4 part tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0yLZnVFJjw  which shows you how to build a view based  NSTableView with buttons.

Your idea in hooking the button to an action is correct. And you do not need to subclass anything.

But check your delegate for TableView is set in IB to the same class that has the NSTableViewDelegate. i.e if my AppDelegate has the delegate methods for the TableView ( NSTableViewDelegate)  I would set the Delegate for the TableView in IB to AppDelegate

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why this works, but I had the same problem and was able to get it working by assigning the table delegate and datasource to the file owner within IB, which is also the class of my click handlers. Only then did it seem to actually bind the click handlers for the buttons in my cell view. Previously I was setting the delegate and datasource in code after the view was loaded.

Comment: First, I verified and you're correct - it only works when the NSTableView has a delegate. The weirdest thing of all --- if you set the 'action' or the 'doubleAction' of the NSTableView itself - it DOES work, regardless of having a delegate. My feeling is there is a nasty apple BUG in the implementation of View-based NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass NSTableCellView class. put your onClick Action method in subclass files.
Let me know if i am not clear..

Comment: I assume you mean `NSTableCellView`? I subclassed this and pasted the action method in there but when I drag the line from the `NSButton` to the method in this class it doesn't connect.

Comment: ya i meant that only.. before that, have you assigned your subclass to TableCellView in IB? you have to put it in its identity inspector. If it does not solve your issue, let me know

Comment: Yep I'm using this subclass for the view that contains my button and textfield. Still won't allow it to connect.

Comment: Make sure that button is subview of your tableCell